# git reset --soft ~HEAD-1 returns no such user or named directory: HEAD-1

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Currently, I am trying to run:

```
git reset --soft ~HEAD-1
```

However; I am getting

```
zsh: no such user or named directory: HEAD-1
```

I'm not exactly whats wrong with my environment. I've tried to reinstall zsh.

I see this when I run git log.

commit 65be5cd472b3d2e7639702f7e1b43a7a47dea863 (HEAD -> development, origin/development)

Comment: Maybe you meant `HEAD^1` or `HEAD~1`?

Comment: https://backlog.com/git-tutorial/using-branches/git-switch-branches/

Comment: Thank you @evolutionxbox - I'm an idiot haha.

Comment: thank you @cyril-jouve

Comment: Not an idiot. I've done this many times. (or maybe we're both idiots... nah)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The command you are looking for is like the following one.

  ```sh
  $ git reset --soft HEAD~1
  ```
- The following syntax is also correct.

  ```sh
  $ git reset --soft HEAD^1
  ```